# zariski closure of a subset of determinantal variety

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to compute the Zariski closure of the following set of $n \times n$ matrices (over $\mathbb{C}$).
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A}=\{X\in\mathcal{M}_{n,n}: X^*=X,~ \text{rank}(X)=1, Tr(X)=1\}.
\end{equation}
In other words, these are all rank $1$ Hermitian operators. (The last condition is perhaps not required in actual computation.)

This is a subset of determinantal varieties of rank $1$ matrices. My guess is, this will be  the Zariski closure of $\mathcal{A}$. However I may be wrong (my Algebraic geometry knowledge is very basis and not proper and this is not my area of work). Advanced thanks for any help or suggestion.

Comment: This is an intersection of rank 1 matrices, which are zariski closed. And hermitian, which doesn't seem to me as Zariski closed, because I didn't make out an algebraic condition of being conjugate over C.